# Maven dependencies download only on command line and not in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, ssl

I've searched through several related topics here on StackOverflow, but the solutions do not work for me.  I've added the -D parameters to my jvm in Eclipse.ini, specifying the keystore and truststore (both cacerts on my machine) and their passwords.  Still, I can only get dependencies to download on the command line and Eclipse continues to complain about PKIX errors.  I need to make Eclipse do the right thing in a global fashion; our dependencies will always come from our internal repository, which is a mirror for the public repositories as well as hosting our internally produced dependencies. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Oddly enough, I had to restart Eclipse more than once for it to "see" the ini file changes.  Not sure what happened there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to mark this as answered so it doesn't bother anyone else.  I had to restart Eclipse more than once for it to see the ini file changes.  Not sure why though.